# I'm trying to change my Maze traversal recursive coding part into a while loop

Tags: c++, iteration

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Direction { EAST, NORTH, WEST, SOUTH };
const int size = 12;
int xStart = 2; int yStart = 0;

char *maze2[ ] = {
    "############",
    "#...#......#",
    "..#.#.####.#",
    "###.#....#.#",
    "#....###.#..",
    "####.#.#.#.#",
    "#..#.#.#.#.#",
    "##.#.#.#.#.#",
    "#........#.#",
    "######.###.#",
    "#......#...#",
    "############",
};
void printMaze ( char maze[][ size ] );
void mazeTraverse( char maze[][ size ], int x, int y, int direction );

int main()
{
    char maze[ size ][ size ];
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++ )
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            maze[ x ][ y ] = maze2[ x ][ y ];
    printMaze( maze );
    mazeTraverse( maze, xStart, yStart, EAST);
}

void printMaze ( char maze[][ size ] )
{
    for ( int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        for ( int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            cout << maze[ x ][ y ];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nHit return to see next move\n";
    cin.get();
}
bool validMove( char maze[][ size ], int x, int y )
{
    return x >= 0 && x < size && y >= 0 && y < size && maze[x][y] != '#';
}

bool coordsAreEdge( int x, int y )
{
    return x== 0 || x== size - 1 || y == 0 || y== size - 1;
}

void mazeTraverse( char maze[][ size ], int x, int y, int direction )
{
    maze[ x ][ y ] = 'x';
    printMaze( maze );
    if (coordsAreEdge(x, y) && (x != xStart || y!= yStart ))
    {
        cout <<"\nMaze successfully exited!\n\n";
        return;
    }else{
        for ( int move = direction, count = 0; count < 4;
            count++, move++, move %=4 )
        {
            int nextX; int nextY;
            switch ( move )
            {
            case SOUTH: nextX = x + 1; nextY = y; break;
            case EAST: nextX = x; nextY = y + 1; break;
            case NORTH: nextX = x - 1; nextY = y; break;
            case WEST: nextX = x; nextY = y - 1; break;
            default: ;
            }
            if (validMove( maze, nextX, nextY ))
            {
                //Recursion move part 1
                //mazeTraverse ( maze,  nextX ,  nextY, (move + 3)%4 );


                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make my void mazeTraverse function a while loop, instead of the recursion and I'm stuck.

Comment: Is that `return` statement inside the `if (validMove` part there in the working recursive version?

Answer (score 2):

Create a struct to hold X, Y and direction (the three things that change between calls). We'll call that struct `State`;

Create a `std::stack<State>` object.  Push the current values of X,Y, direction onto the stack before you change them, pop them after you do your work.

hence

```
 while(.....)
 {
      push state
      Do work of mazeTraverse 
      pop state
 }
```

Comment: I've never used the "Do" statement, I'm not sure what you're meaning by do work on mazeTraverse. Should I just copy and paste my mazeTraverse function in between the push and pop states?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he just meant the comment "do whatever work you have here".  The syntax highlighter just got a little slap happy with keyword coloration.

Answer (score 0):

It would've been nice if you described how the traversal works. If I'm not reading the code wrong, you are basically moving south/east/north/west on any position that doesn't contain a # and is within the bounds of the matrix.

You can do this iteratively by using a BF search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search or, applied to a matrix, the Lee algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm which can be efficiently implemented using a FIFO queue, which I describe how to do here: [Change FloodFill-Algorithm to get Voronoi Territory for two data points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288830/change-floodfill-algorithm-to-get-voronoi-territory-for-two-data-points/2288898#2288898)

Your validMove function will stay the same: you add a position to the queue only if that position is valid. Basically all checks stay the same, just that you use a FIFO queue to hold your states instead of an implicit stack.

Comment: Yeah, its a simple program that moves in whatever direction it can that does not contain a #. It keeps going till it finishes. With the recursion it works fine, but I'm trying to figure out a way to use a while loop.

Comment: You can use a while loop in a BF search. Check my third link. Basically, you extract a position from your queue while there are still positions left to be extracted, and you add that position's valid neighbours to the queue. Eventually, you will end up not being able to add anything, and so the algorithm (the while loop) will terminate. Your current recursive solution looks like a DF search - do you want to make the DF search non-recursive? If so, then James Curran's solution is the right one, although I personally suggest a BF search.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a breadth-first search instead using a standard `queue` and `while` loop.

```
typedef pair<int, int> Point;

queue<Point> path;

Point start(xStart, yStart);
path.push(start);

const int move_x[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
const int move_y[] = {0, -1, 0, 1};

while (!path.empty())
{
  Point p = path.front();
  int x = p.first, y = p.second;
  maze[x][y] = 'x';

  path.pop();

  if (coordsAreEdge(x,y) && p != start)
  {
    // Finished
    break;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    int newx = x + move_x[i];
    int newy = y + move_y[i];

    if (validMove(maze, newx, newy))
      path.push(Point(newx, newy));
  }
}
```

That should do the trick. Note that it's untested though.

You can improve its performance by using A* instead, but that's a little more complex. Let me know if you need to find the shortest path from this code as well.

EDIT: Note that if you change the `queue` to a `stack` (and change `path.front()` to `path.top()`) then you'll get a depth-first search (DFS) instead, which is what your code does. The DFS, however, doesn't find the shortest path (if that is necessary).